# listen clcik event in while loop

Tags: java, swing, applet, actionlistener

Hello I am working on a Java Applet.

I have the requirements of listening for click events in a `while` loop.
However, after entering the `while` loop the quit button is not responding.
So my requirement is after clicking on quit button the applet will be closed.

```
package app;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class test extends Applet implements ActionListener{
     Image img;
     Button b;
     Button b1;
     boolean quit = false;
     //String actionMessage="";

     public void init(){

        b=new Button("Start");
        b1=new Button("Quit");
        add(b);
        add(b1);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
     }
       public void paint(Graphics g){
          b.setLocation(70, 350);
          b1.setLocation(180, 350);
          g.drawImage(img,10,20,300,300,this);

          this.setSize(322,380);

          //g.drawString(actionMessage, 10, 50);
     }

       Button source =null;   
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
           OuterLoop:

        source = (Button)ae.getSource();



    if(source.getLabel()=="Start"){
               img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "images/S2T.png");
               repaint();
               System.out.println("HI");
               quit = true;
                 test t1 = new test ();
                 t1.voce();
           }

           if(source.getLabel()=="Quit"){
               System.out.println("Hello");

               quit = false;
               test t1 = new test ();
             t1.voce();
           }

           /*       if(ae.getSource()==b){
             img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "images/S2T.png");
             repaint();
             quit = true;
             test t1 = new test ();
             t1.voce();
             //actionMessage="Speak now";

        }

        if(ae.getSource()==b1){
             img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "images/S2T1.png");
             //actionMessage="Thanks for using this Software";
             repaint();
             quit = false;
               test t1 = new test ();
             t1.voce();
             System.exit(0);         
        }*/

     }  


    public void voce(){
           voce.SpeechInterface.init("D:/Project/VoiceRecognization/src/", false, true, 
                    "file:D:/Project/VoiceRecognization/src/", "digits");

                System.out.println("This is a speech recognition test. " 
                    + "Speak digits from 0-9 into the microphone. " 
                    + "Speak 'quit' to quit.");

                while (!quit)
                {

                    // Normally, applications would do application-specific things 
                    // here.  For this sample, we'll just sleep for a little bit.
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    while (voce.SpeechInterface.getRecognizerQueueSize() > 0)
                    {
                        String s = voce.SpeechInterface.popRecognizedString();

                        if(s.equals("san")){
                            System.out.println("DONE IT !!!!!!!!!!!!!" );
                            Runtime rs = Runtime.getRuntime();
                            try{
                                /*rs.exec("notepad");*/
                                //rs.exec("explorer.exe");
                                rs.exec("explorer d:\\Project\\VoiceRecognization");
                                //Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\folder"));
                            }catch(Exception ie){
                                ie.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println("Done");                 
                        }else if(s.equals("hello")){
                            System.out.println("DONE IT !!!!!!!!!!!!!" );
                            Runtime rs = Runtime.getRuntime();
                            try{
                                /*rs.exec("notepad");*/
                                rs.exec("explorer =");
                                /*rs.exec("explorer d:\\Project\\VoiceRecognization");*/
                                //Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\folder"));
                            }catch(Exception ie){
                                ie.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println("Done");                 
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("In the else part");
                        }


                        // Check if the string contains 'quit'.
                        if (-1 != s.indexOf("quit"))
                        {
                            quit = true;
                            System.out.println("NOT DONE IT +++++++++++ " );
                        }

                        System.out.println("You said: " + s);
                        //voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize(s);



                     }
                    continue OuterLoop;
}
                }
       }
```

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) and [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: You problem is likely one associated with concurrency, you are blocking the event dispatching thread which will prevent the UI from responding to new events until the while loop exists

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: Can you suggest me some example from that , So I can run my loop on separate thread .